# Mapbox Click label of a feature and zoom to feature bounds, like Google Maps

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

This is a basic webmap feature, but I'm not finding it anywhere.

I want to do what they have in google maps - the labels are like links, and when you click on a label of a place that's a polygon or line it zooms to the bounds of that place.

Try it here, click on "Des Moines" here, or any other feature:
https://www.google.com/maps/@41.5241414,-93.5651933,9.33z

This is the closest thing I've found, but it's with a button rather than a link.
Zoom to Bounds: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/